# Terminating multi-mode fiber

Tags: networking, fiber

I'm looking at the feasibility of terminating multi-mode fiber connections ourselves.   We would be using LC connectors.  I've done some research and found two different methods.  One requires polishing the ends and using epoxy while the other doesn't.  I like the idea of not having to polish the ends but there doesn't seem to be much information on quality or ease of use.  I've found two vendors (3M and Corning) that offer kits for terminating fiber without polishing or using epoxy.  Does anyone have any experience with both methods that can offer some advice?  Copper is easy but fiber seems to be a whole different animal.

EDIT:  After looking into fusion splicing suggested in the answer I've determined it's not for us.  It's my understanding that is primarily used for outside plant and is better suited for single mode fiber.  It's a good answer but doesn't address the question directly.

Some more information about our situation.  We will only be terminating multi-mode fiber inside a building and only doing between 4 and 20 pair a year.  Hiring an outside person won't work due to our location.  There are currently a couple people on-site that can terminate fiber (working for another company and charging large fees) but they can only do ST and SC connectors and we only use LC.  So once again does anyone have experience with terminating using both epoxy type connectors and the other type (similar to Corning Unicam)?

Comment: The most important thing here is what *specific* type of fibre are you planning on using and for what transfer speeds? For instance if using OM3 for 8Gbps FC or 10Gbps Ethernet I'd pay a professional every time, I simply wouldn't consider doing it myself.

Comment: Strictly 1Gbps connections between network devices and occasionally between a network device and host.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'd only use [fusion splicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_splicing) for terminations. Unfortunately, the equipment required for the job is expensive and isn't going to be cost effective unless you have a lot of terminations to do. Also you will need somebody with skills to do the job.

Otherwise, I'd suggest getting a specialist in to do the work for you.

Comment: +1 for Fusion Splicing.  You can hire the splicers for not too much money.  Better still, hire a specialist to do them for you, it's a fiddly job, and best left to professionals.

Comment: Is fusion splicing also used for terminating connections or is it just used for splicing fiber?

Comment: Yes, you would use a pigtail i.e. A short single length of fibre with your LC connector (socket) on one end, and you fusion splice the other end to your fibre, obviously, repeat the process at both ends of your fibre.